# Liquid gets less/vanishes if effector is rotated in animation

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I am experimenting with liquids in an animation, but I don't get it to work properly.

I have an simple container, liquid flows in. Then it rotates so the collected liquid should be able to flow of another hole, which the liquid reaches by this rotation.

But instead it "collapses" in one corner and almost vanishes.

I have attached a sample .blend-File, with almost default settings of "Quick Liquid".

[liquid_rotation.blend](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1165986472441159771/1190968071872065626/liquid_rotation.blend?ex=65a3ba73&is=65914573&hm=a84ab833495dd79ef1c7a75efa1d3268d6862e6eaeaab1791f5f836f9710678a&)

**Edit:** I am using version `4.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot "really" explain why this happens (i just think it might be because of rounding issues), but "normally" you can achieve better results in fluid simulations with higher resolution divisions.

So here is your result with 128 (instead of 32):

[image]

so you might even get better results with even higher resolutions, but of course with the cost of much more time to bake that.

Comment: For the final bake, increasing the divisions would be no problem, but the provided .blend-File is a simplified version of one I am working on atm. There, even a resolultion of 128 does not work and higher ones make planning my scene almost unbearable :-(